# Re-arrange tables

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm using query to get data from a database. My problem is that the arrangement of data is not so user friendly.

My data comes in the following format, .. only a lot bigger table:

```
Measurand    Date   Trunk 1 Trunk 2 Trunk 3 Trunk 4

a 1.1.2012 00:00 Value.a.1 Value.a.2 Value.a.3 Value.a.4

b 1.1.2012 00:00 Value.b.1 Value.b.2 Value.b.3 Value.b.4

c 1.1.2012 00:00 Value.c.1 Value.c.2 Value.c.3 Value.c.4

a 2.1.2012 00:00 Value.a.5 Value.a.6 Value.a.7 Value.a.8

b 2.1.2012 00:00 Value.b.5 Value.b.6 Value.b.7 Value.b.8

c 2.1.2012 00:00 Value.c.5 Value.c.6 Value.c.7 Value.c.8

a 3.1.2012 00:00 Value.a.9 Value.a.10 Value.a.11 Value.a.12

b 3.1.2012 00:00 Value.b.9 Value.b.10 Value.b.11 Value.b.12

c 3.1.2012 00:00 Value.c.9 Value.c.10 Value.c.11 Value.c.12
```

I want to write a formula or do some voodoo to make it look like:

```
Date a b c

1.1.2012 00:00  Value.a.1   Value.b.1   Value.c.1

1.1.2012 00:00  Value.a.2   Value.b.2   Value.c.2

1.1.2012 00:00  Value.a.3   Value.b.3   Value.c.3

1.1.2012 00:00  Value.a.4   Value.b.4   Value.c.4

2.1.2012 00:00  Value.a.5   Value.b.5   Value.c.5

2.1.2012 00:00  Value.a.6   Value.b.6   Value.c.6

2.1.2012 00:00  Value.a.7   Value.b.7   Value.c.7

2.1.2012 00:00  Value.a.8   Value.b.8   Value.c.8

3.1.2012 00:00  Value.a.9   Value.b.9   Value.c.9

3.1.2012 00:00  Value.a.10  Value.b.10  Value.c.10

3.1.2012 00:00  Value.a.11  Value.b.11  Value.c.11

3.1.2012 00:00  Value.a.12  Value.b.12  Value.c.12
```

I know it's a horrible display, but I can't insert pictures due to lack of points.

Comment: Is this data actually split into separate rows and columns? Or is it just all in column A (like one of those terrible output files)?

Comment: Hi. I have 40 different measurand id and 24 trunks. Basically every trunk shows the value of the a hour of the day in the date column (that's why they are 24). So every 40 lines, I have the same measurands, just for the next day. Thankfully the data is split into separate columns and rows.

Comment: @pnuts This is something I'd like to do on daily basis with different number of lines, but fixed number of columns (Say (1-40)x24)

Comment: @teitifeiti or perhaps you might be better off using python to process the file before you even open it.

Answer (score 0):

The laziest option I can see here would be to create a pivot table with your whole table as the input range, setting trunk1-trunk4 as data fields (in that order), with measurand as a column field and date as a row field. This will give you the layout you want, as long as there is only 1 value per measurand per trunk per date.

As long as you don't keep adding lots of new trunks it shouldn't be too much work to keep it updated. I don't think there's any easy way of adding loads of data fields in one go unless you resort to a bit of VBA.